# what is the equivalent of double precision number to quad precision in fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

What is direct equivalent of double precision number: **dble(number)** to a quadruple precision number (**quad(number)**?) in Fortran 90?

Comment: Naturally, don't use `real(number,16)` but find the appropriate kind number instead.  Possibly `real(number,real128)` or something from `selected_real_kind`.

Comment: The other option is if you have specified quad via say integer, parameter :: qp = selected_real_kind(p=30) then you can declare a number using number_qp instead of real(number,qp)